# Trying to get table to fit on one page

Tags: tables, fonts, positioning

I am switching from writing documents in Word to LaTeX and am struggling to get a table to fit on one page. The table fits oon the page with the `geometry`  package, which defines mre sensible margins by default, if you don't use marginal notes.

I am using the following code to build the table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
    \toprule
    {} & U.S. AUC & U.S. Accuracy & U.S. Acc Std & U.S. Rank & Global AUC & Global Accuracy & Global Acc Std & Global Rank \\
    \midrule \\
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Individual}} \\
    AB  &   0.6061  &   0.1648  &   0.0018  &   11  &   0.643   &   0.1446  &   0.0158  &   13 \\
    BNB &   0.8035  &   0.1524  &   0.0023  &   12  &   0.8059  &   0.166   &   0.0034  &   12 \\
    DT  &   0.6027  &   0.6516  &   0.0047  &   4   &   0.629   &   0.7605  &   0.0081  &   4 \\
    ET  &   0.9768  &   0.9166  &   0.0012  &   1   &   0.9839  &   0.915   &   0.0028  &   1 \\
    GNB &   0.5048  &   0.0514  &   0.0061  &   14  &   0.499   &   0.0629  &   0.0038  &   14 \\
    HGB &   0.6286  &   0.52    &   0.029   &   6   &   0.5054  &   0.6538  &   0.0206  &   6 \\
    KNN &   0.6822  &   0.2323  &   0.0031  &   9   &   0.797   &   0.4182  &   0.0061  &   8 \\
    LDA &   0.8283  &   0.2292  &   0.0038  &   10  &   0.7513  &   0.2637  &   0.0066  &   10 \\
    LR  &   0.8189  &   0.2344  &   0.0035  &   8   &   0.829   &   0.2736  &   0.0073  &   9 \\
    MLP &   0.918   &   0.486   &   0.0024  &   7   &   0.8742  &   0.6589  &   0.0061  &   5 \\
    QDA &   0.5038  &   0.1148  &   0.0043  &   13  &   0.5002  &   0.25    &   0.005   &   11 \\
    RF  &   0.9568  &   0.8868  &   0.0012  &   2   &   0.9619  &   0.9055  &   0.0029  &   2 \\
    SVM &           &   0.5516  &   0.0024  &   5   &           &   0.5487  &   0.0073  &   7 \\
    XGB &   0.9824  &   0.8107  &   0.0022  &   3   &   0.9771  &   0.8776  &   0.0049  &   3 \\
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Medium}} \\
    AB  &   0.8311  &   0.7298  &   0.0017  &   8   &   0.7575  &   0.7034  &   0.0109  &   9 \\
    BNB &   0.8149  &   0.6038  &   0.006   &   12  &   0.7643  &   0.5338  &   0.0056  &   12 \\
    DT  &   0.6692  &   0.8604  &   0.003   &   5   &   0.6713  &   0.905   &   0.0055  &   5 \\
    ET  &   0.9853  &   0.9512  &   0.0007  &   1   &   0.9907  &   0.9663  &   0.0022  &   1 \\
    GNB &   0.5224  &   0.3248  &   0.0086  &   14  &   0.5126  &   0.3713  &   0.0032  &   14 \\
    HGB &   0.9350  &   0.9056  &   0.0019  &   4   &   0.9427  &   0.9584  &   0.0018  &   2 \\
    KNN &   0.8214  &   0.6816  &   0.0024  &   11  &   0.8849  &   0.7606  &   0.0023  &   8 \\
    LDA &   0.8638  &   0.7087  &   0.0053  &   10  &   0.8099  &   0.6786  &   0.003   &   11 \\
    LR  &   0.8710  &   0.7154  &   0.003   &   9   &   0.8238  &   0.6854  &   0.0043  &   10 \\
    MLP &   0.9172  &   0.8532  &   0.0031  &   6   &   0.9066  &   0.8913  &   0.0025  &   6 \\
    QDA &   0.5001  &   0.3839  &   0.0411  &   13  &   0.5004  &   0.4429  &   0.0074  &   13 \\
    RF  &   0.9480  &   0.9343  &   0.0016  &   2   &   0.9375  &   0.9584  &   0.0024  &   2 \\
    SVM &   0.9178  &   0.7747  &   0.0033  &   7   &           &   0.7953  &   0.003   &   7 \\ 
    XGB &   0.997   &   0.9284  &   0.002   &   3   &   0.9893  &   0.9182  &   0.0018  &   4 \\
    \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have tried using `tabularx`, `adjustbox`, changing font size with the various methods the forums mention. The desired table (as is in Word) I am trying to achieve is attached. Any help for a newbie to LaTeX would be awesome!
[image: Word table]

Comment: What's the document class you use?

Comment: please fix the example so it can be run to see the problem, without knowing the page size and font size impossible to know how much space you need to save

Comment: Have to follow a university guideline document. This is class used: 
LoadClass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}

Comment: please edit the question so the example can be run even if that just needs adding the documentclass and begin and end document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table will look better using the `S` column type to align the numbers on the decimal dot and adding some more vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}

 \begin{document}


 \begin{table}[h]
 \centering\sisetup{table-format=1.4, table-number-alignment=center}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
 \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{SSSS[table-format=2]}}
    \toprule
    {} & {\thead{U.S. \\ AUC}} & {\thead{U.S.\\ Accuracy}} & {\thead{U.S.\\ Acc Std}} & {\thead{U.S.\\ Rank}} & {\thead{Global\\ AUC}} & {\thead{Global\\ Accuracy }}& {\thead{Global\\ Acc Std}} & {\thead{Global\\ Rank}} \\
    \midrule\addlinespace
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Individual}} \\
\addlinespace
    AB & 0.6061 & 0.1648 & 0.0018 & 11 & 0.643 & 0.1446 & 0.0158 & 13 \\
    BNB & 0.8035 & 0.1524 & 0.0023 & 12 & 0.8059 & 0.166 & 0.0034 & 12 \\
    DT & 0.6027 & 0.6516 & 0.0047 & 4 & 0.629 & 0.7605 & 0.0081 & 4 \\
    ET & 0.9768 & 0.9166 & 0.0012 & 1 & 0.9839 & 0.915 & 0.0028 & 1 \\
    GNB & 0.5048 & 0.0514 & 0.0061 & 14 & 0.499 & 0.0629 & 0.0038 & 14 \\
    HGB & 0.6286 & 0.52 & 0.029 & 6 & 0.5054 & 0.6538 & 0.0206 & 6 \\
    KNN & 0.6822 & 0.2323 & 0.0031 & 9 & 0.797 & 0.4182 & 0.0061 & 8 \\
    LDA & 0.8283 & 0.2292 & 0.0038 & 10 & 0.7513 & 0.2637 & 0.0066 & 10 \\
    LR & 0.8189 & 0.2344 & 0.0035 & 8 & 0.829 & 0.2736 & 0.0073 & 9 \\
    MLP & 0.918 & 0.486 & 0.0024 & 7 & 0.8742 & 0.6589 & 0.0061 & 5 \\
    QDA & 0.5038 & 0.1148 & 0.0043 & 13 & 0.5002 & 0.25 & 0.005 & 11 \\
    RF & 0.9568 & 0.8868 & 0.0012 & 2 & 0.9619 & 0.9055 & 0.0029 & 2 \\
    SVM & & 0.5516 & 0.0024 & 5 & & 0.5487 & 0.0073 & 7 \\
    XGB & 0.9824 & 0.8107 & 0.0022 & 3 & 0.9771 & 0.8776 & 0.0049 & 3 \\
\addlinespace[2ex]
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Medium}} \\
\addlinespace
    AB & 0.8311 & 0.7298 & 0.0017 & 8 & 0.7575 & 0.7034 & 0.0109 & 9 \\
    BNB & 0.8149 & 0.6038 & 0.006 & 12 & 0.7643 & 0.5338 & 0.0056 & 12 \\
    DT & 0.6692 & 0.8604 & 0.003 & 5 & 0.6713 & 0.905 & 0.0055 & 5 \\
    ET & 0.9853 & 0.9512 & 0.0007 & 1 & 0.9907 & 0.9663 & 0.0022 & 1 \\
    GNB & 0.5224 & 0.3248 & 0.0086 & 14 & 0.5126 & 0.3713 & 0.0032 & 14 \\
    HGB & 0.9350 & 0.9056 & 0.0019 & 4 & 0.9427 & 0.9584 & 0.0018 & 2 \\
    KNN & 0.8214 & 0.6816 & 0.0024 & 11 & 0.8849 & 0.7606 & 0.0023 & 8 \\
    LDA & 0.8638 & 0.7087 & 0.0053 & 10 & 0.8099 & 0.6786 & 0.003 & 11 \\
    LR & 0.8710 & 0.7154 & 0.003 & 9 & 0.8238 & 0.6854 & 0.0043 & 10 \\
    MLP & 0.9172 & 0.8532 & 0.0031 & 6 & 0.9066 & 0.8913 & 0.0025 & 6 \\
    QDA & 0.5001 & 0.3839 & 0.0411 & 13 & 0.5004 & 0.4429 & 0.0074 & 13 \\
    RF & 0.9480 & 0.9343 & 0.0016 & 2 & 0.9375 & 0.9584 & 0.0024 & 2 \\
    SVM & 0.9178 & 0.7747 & 0.0033 & 7 & & 0.7953 & 0.003 & 7 \\
    XGB & 0.997 & 0.9284 & 0.002 & 3 & 0.9893 & 0.9182 & 0.0018 & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]